# How to create the output text file in the respective sub directories in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I selected all (.txt) files which are present in all the sub directories within the root directory by using the following code.

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
dirname = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select a directory')
pattern = "*.txt"
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(dirname):
    for name in files:
        if fnmatch(name, pattern):
            filename=os.path.join(path,name)
```

Now I have got some 100 (.txt) files which are present in the different sub-directories. Now I use NLTK to analyse the (.txt) files and I want to save the output in the respective sub-directories as individual (.txt) file.

How to save the output in the respective folder from where the main (.txt) source file is present ?

(* The root directory is not the current working directory. It is different)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`os.path.dirname()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) to get the path of the directory a file resides in.

If you need to generate a new filename based of the old one, you could use [`os.path.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) instead, to split a filename into a directory and base name:

```
directory, base = os.path.split(filename)
new_filename = os.path.join(directory, 'analyzed_' + filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your solution is within O(n), then just walk read and write.

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
dirname = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select a 

directory')
pattern = "*.txt"
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(dirname):
    for name in files:
        if fnmatch(name, pattern):
            filename=os.path.join(path,name)
            new_filename=os.path.join(path,'new'+name)
            #do your work for filename and save to new_filename
```

if you need to sum these files up and do some work after loading them all. You need to save their path respectively.